# R: Collect intermediate output of recursive function

Tags: r, recursion, tail-recursion

I have a recursive function that uses the output of the previous call as the input of the next call:

```
recurse_foo = function(input) {
  if(identical(input, character(0))) return(NULL)
  else {
    uu = get_incremental_output(input)  ## <-- interested in collecting this
    return(recurse_foo(uu))
  }
}
```

As is evident, the terminal output is not very interesting, and I am interested in collecting the intermediate output, but I cannot imagine that growing a global list or any other side effect would be elegant (which is the only thing I can think of).

Any other abstractions that might be useful here?

Thanks.

---

Specific example:

```
final_countdown = function(input) {
  if (input/2 < 1) return(NULL)
  else {
    uu = input/2         # <-- interested in collecting this
    print(uu)
    return(final_countdown(uu))
  }
}

final_countdown(100)
```

In this case, I am interested in collecting the sequence of `uu`s that are `print`ed.

Comment: It would be good to have an example input, and the desired result.

Comment: Maybe you can write it into a text file and not keep in memory at all? Later you can use it where necessary

Comment: @PorkChop Yes, I mentioned that side effects (including writing to file) are options. I was hoping for a more purely functional way of doing this.

Comment: @LuisUsier Sure. It is straightforward to create a concrete example, and I have added one. I am more interested in the abstractions that R allows in this case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, if all intermediate outputs are of the same type:

```
final_countdown = function(input) {
  if (input/2 < 1) return(NA)
  else {
    c(input, final_countdown(input/2))
  }
}
```

Comment: `c(input/2, final_countdown(input/2))`, but very nice. Very much in the spirit of elegance that I was looking for. I am surprised (annoyed) that this solution did not occur to me. ;)